# PYTHON - pyperclip installing issue

Tags: python, pyperclip

I'm following a course on Udemy: Automate the Boring Stuff using Python. For one of the courses the guide asks me to install Pyperclip. Now I've tried this, but cmd keeps returning:  " 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable or batch file

The path I use is "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe", I've tried it without the pip.exe, but then it also returns an error.

Comment: You do not give us enough information to help you. But if you cannot execute the `pip` command, the problem is not with `pyperclip` but with your Python installation.

Comment: I've fixed it, I tried out C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe install pyperclip in a single line, which worked

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, I tried out "C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe install pyperclip", and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 has pip embedded, so you can use python3 directly to install it:

```
python3 -m pip install <package>
```